# How to convert image to EPS file without leaving any margins with MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, eps

I am converting images to EPS files with the following script.

```
%% Image 2 eps file.
% - img: the image.
% - eps: eps filename.
function Image2Eps(img, eps)
    imshow(img,'border','tight','InitialMagnification',100);
    print(gcf,'-depsc',eps);
end
```

The file generated almost bound the image tightly.
But a small margin is always left on the top and on the right side.
How to make the EPS file exactly the size of the bitmap image?

Comment: why are you using Matlab for this task? why not using `gs`?

Comment: This is the relevant comment in the documentation, perhaps it helps: `Note: There can still be a border if the image is very small, or if there are other objects besides the image and its axes in the figure.`
Besides preventing it from happening you may be able to remove the border afterwards?

Comment: Shai: can you give some further ideas about converting bitmap images to eps with ghostscript? A command line for demonstration?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not too locked on Matlab. You can use [Image Magick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to do the conversion.
I used it in a command line:

```
imgtops2.exe imge.ppm -e -c 0,0 -o image.eps
```

I used it on a Windows machine, but I believe they have working binaries for other OS as well.

Furthermore, once you have a working command line in `dos` or `shell` you can call it from Matlab using [`system`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html), [`dos`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dos.html) or [`unix`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unix.html) commands.

PS.

I used an old version of ImageMagick, in more recent releases they might have changed `imgtops2` to `convert`, you'll have to look at their documentation.